# Unable to get xemacs working on a mac

Tags: macos, xemacs

I installed xemacs using macports, and then when I try to open it I see this -

$xemacs
Error: Shell widget xemacs has zero width and/or height

I tried to google for this error message, but there were no helpful hits. How can I get xemacs to start without this error? Thanks

Comment: You might be happier with aquamacs.

Comment: You can also try out Carbon Emacs if you don' t like Aquamacs customizations. http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/unix_open_source/carbonemacspackage.html

Comment: I installed aquamacs, seems to do the job and has a fairly decent user manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To eliminate the problem completely and to bring some joy to your life.... try [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/).

p.s. stupid question, but do you have the [x-server installed](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/runningx11.html) ?